# How to search keywords with product counts by given name in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have multiple keywords for each product. I want to search by keyword with product count

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?facet.field=keywords&q=keywords%3A%2AWeicher%2A&q.op=AND&rows=10&wt=json&indent=on&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&fl=keywords,name

```
 {     
  "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "name":["Transportbeton - 1"],
    "keywords":["Beton",
      "Weicher Beton"]},
  {
    "name":["Transportbeton -  2"],
    "keywords":["Beton",
      "Weicher Beton"]},
  {
    "name":["Transportbeton - 3"],
    "keywords":["Beton",
      "Weicher Beton"]}
  ]   
},
"facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{
  "keywords":[
    "Beton",3,
    "Weicher Beton",3]},
"facet_ranges":{},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}
}
```

Here I m searching only keywords which contain "Weicher" word. But I m getting other keyword in results as well.

How i can get only those keywords (with product counts) which match with given input?

Answer (score 0):

Solr has a facet feature where you can provide a facet condition. Refer https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.field

Answer (score 0):

Use Facets.  facet.field=keyword(field name)

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&facet=true&facet.field=keywords
```

Comment: I have tried facet but getting other keywords as well which does not match with input

Comment: Use facet.query.  `facet.query=keyword:Weicher`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **facet.prefix** parameter. It will Limits the terms used for faceting to those that begin with the specified prefix.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&facet=true&facet.field=keywords&facet.prefix=Weicher`

Also you can use **facet.contains**. It will Limits the terms used for faceting to those that contain the specified substring.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json&facet=true&facet.field=keywords&
facet.contains=Weicher
```

Comment: I suggest `facet.query=Weicher`   facet.prefix wont match conatins like Beton Weicher

Comment: Yes well that's true it will only give the result which will starts with Weicher .

Comment: facet.query does not give expected result. result might contain more than one keywords like 
Weicher (4),
WeicherPost (2),
Best Weicher (1)